# if condition with false never work ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

currently i am updating some value on `if` condition in my `api` as

```
motion_detection.frequency = frequency if frequency
motion_detection.minPosition = minPosition if minPosition
motion_detection.step = step if step
motion_detection.min = min if min
motion_detection.threshold = threshold if threshold
motion_detection.enabled = enabled

motion_detection.alert_email = alert_email if alert_email
motion_detection.alert_interval_min = alert_interval_min if alert_interval_min
motion_detection.sensitivity = sensitivity if sensitivity
motion_detection.x1 = x1 if x1
motion_detection.x2 = x2 if x2
motion_detection.y1 = y1 if y1
motion_detection.y2 = y2 if y2
motion_detection.schedule = JSON.parse(inputs["schedule"]) if schedule
motion_detection.save

motion_detection
```

while if i put `motion_detection.enabled = enabled if enabled`
then it once goes `TRUE`, it never comes back to `FALSE` even if i put `enabled = false`. why is it so? i want it to run for false as well when i may put enabled false but it only works for `TRUE` then never get back to false

Comment: I am sorry.. I didn't see that part...

Comment: if i get your question right.. your want to get `if` working when you put `enabled = false`.. my question is if you are putting `enabled = false` why do you think the `if` condition would work..?

Comment: enabled is a value. I want the solution how to sort it out that if i may put enabled false then it should update the value with FALSE.

Comment: if you want to only assign `motion_detection.enabled = enabled` only when a `value` for `enabled` is provided... to do that you could use.. `motion_detection.enabled = enabled if enabled.present?`.. this way you can assign on `presence` of `enabled` rather than its value..

Comment: it didnt work :) the value was true and is true as well..

Comment: sorry.. I was looking into another thing... its... `unless enabled.nil?` of `if !enabled.nil?`.. here a link to [rbFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/ed4ac/2)

Comment: Okay then put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to only assign `motion_detection.enabled = enabled` only when a `value` for `enabled` is provided...

To do that you could use..

```
motion_detection.enabled = enabled unless enabled.nil?
```

or

```
motion_detection.enabled = enabled if !enabled.nil?
```

this way you can assign on `presence` of `enabled` rather than its `value`..

here is a simple ruby fiddle to illustrate [rubyfiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/ed4ac/3)

Comment: best one is the above one with unless, my lead also preferred that thanks buddy

Comment: @ijunaidfarooq koi nai .. :D

Comment: bari philosophy mari hai twitter pe :P glue wali :D

Comment: @ijunaidfarooq bhai twitter use nai karta main :P

Comment: Acha ji? to wo Mubashir hanif sab kon hen? Allama Iqbal AVI wale? :D

Comment: @ijunaidfarooq chor de bhai... wo purana ho gaya ab to.. twitter pe ro picture bhi Allama wali lagi pari hai :P

Comment: haha sahi hai :P follow kia hai ap ko.. follow back kar dena warna answer ko -1 kar don ga :D